# Non Blocking write, and blocking recv

Tags: c, tcp, proxy, nonblocking

I am trying to write a parallel stream for my C proxy, where data is simultaneously written to a parallel log while forwarding it to the destination server. Essentially I am looking to have 2 threads where:

1. Thread does a non blocking write to a buffer
2. 2nd Thread does a blocking read from the buffer.

Naturally, the writer thread can exceed the reader thread. Hence whenever, a buffer overflow does happen, we raise and flag it as an error.

Let's say that Thread 1(the writer), is 5 times as fast as Thread 2( the reader). I want Thread 1 not to slowdown, and write at 5x the speed of the reader (i.e. the buffer should not be locked away by the reader etc.). This will obviously lead to a buffer overflow since thread 1 is writing much faster than thread 2 is reading( I want to capture buffer overflow as well)

My understanding is sockets/file descriptors are either blocking or non blocking, cannot have write operations as non blocking and read as blocking. I am guessing this is to avoid buffer overflows. However, I am fine with buffer overflows.

Can anyone help in devising how such parallel threads can be created where the producer is non blocking, and the receiver is blocking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select()` to block until the socket is readable. Leave it in non-blocking mode. If `send()` returns `-1` and `errno` is set to `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` then you will need to use `select()` to tell you when the socket has become *writable* again. Only do that when `send()` reports `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, as sockets are almost always writable.

Comment: Please excuse me if my understanding is not totally correct, I am looking into the select system call. I understand select tells when a file descriptor is ready for write/read I/O operations. I would like to re-iterate that I don't want the speed of the write operations to be reduced because the read operations are slow... will select help me in doing that?

Comment: @nipun Yes, it will. You'll use `select` to block until the socket is readable.

Comment: @nipun: TCP throttles transmissions. If the receive buffer fills up, the send buffer is blocked. You can keep pumping data into `send()` as much as you want, but if the receive buffer fills up then `send()` cannot accept more data and will fail with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` until the receive buffer frees up some room. When that happens, `select()` will tell you when `send()` can accept new data again.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks for the explanation. Quick follow up? 1.Do UNIX sockets also display this throttling behavior. I am not doing this over TCP. (Well there is TCP for the proxy, but this is a duplication of the incoming TCP stream which I am forwarding, and simultaneously buffering to a seperate process. I do not want this buffering to effect the speed of forwarding the tcp traffic. The question is regarding the buffering)

Comment: 2. My understanding for a possible solution following your explanation and reading up on the syscalls is this this-> (a). Create a non blocking file descriptor, (b). Write to the file descriptor using a non-blocking operation (which will give an error when buffer is full) (c). read in another process from this file descriptor, and use select to tell when fd is ready to be read. Is there any way to also specify/control the size of the buffer? I will write up and post the solution once I am done. Thanks a lot for your help already :)

Comment: @nipun: I have no clue how UNIX socket buffering works, I have only used TCP/UDP sockets.  However, for all socket types, you can use `setsockopt()` with `SO_SDBUF` and `SO_RCVBUF` to control the buffer sizes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the corrections, I was thinking in Java of course.